# In Tensorflow 1.8.0, How to combine two placeholder into tuples in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have two placeholder both with 10 values in it. Now I want to convert it to tuple.

In python, I know how to do it, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

c = list(zip(a, b)
```

Then **c=[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]**

So, I have **a** and **b** in placeholder, and how can I get **c**?

Can't use eager execution and placeholder at the same time.

**But the way, my Tensorflow version is 1.8.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `tf.data.Data.from_tensor_slices`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

c = np.asarray(list(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a, b)).map(lambda x, y: (x, y))), dtype="i,i")
print(c)
```

```
[(1, 4) (2, 5) (3, 6)]
```

If you are working with `placeholders`, try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32)
b = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32)

def f(a, b):
  return np.stack([a, b], axis=1)

c = tf.py_func(f, [a, b], tf.int32)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
 c = sess.run(c, feed_dict={a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6]})
 c = [tuple(i) for i in c]
 print(c)
```

```
[(1, 4) (2, 5) (3, 6)]
```

Comment: It's not necessary. @GoldenLion

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  your answer helped me a lot. But there is another question could you help me? What if a and b are tf.placeholder? It mentioned me tf.placholder is not compatible with eager execution

Comment: So, could you give me some advices?

Comment: The project is almost complete, it's almost there. No time to learn other versions. 555555555